# Why is allEffects from effects package excluding a level/value from my my model?

Tags: r, effects

I posted this on stackoverflow but it was suggested I post it here.

I am running an ordinal logistic regression on data that is roughly like this:

```
library(MASS)
library(effects)

df<- structure(list(cov = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                      3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                      2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("High", "Medium", "Low"), class = "factor"), 
                    agec = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                             2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                             4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                             6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                     -60L))


m <- polr(cov ~ agec, data = df, Hess=T)

probs <-allEffects(m)

probs
```

You can see that agec=3 isn't here. agec is a categorized age but I want to run it as numeric.  When I do that, allEffects produces effects that don't include agec=3.  Of course, if I run agec as a factor it includes it.

```
 model: cov ~ agec

agec effect (probability) for High
agec
        1         2         4         5         6 
0.2174030 0.2473099 0.3149013 0.3521847 0.3913608 

agec effect (probability) for Medium
agec
        1         2         4         5         6 
0.3352479 0.3463802 0.3565925 0.3552180 0.3495402 

agec effect (probability) for Low
agec
        1         2         4         5         6 
0.4473491 0.4063099 0.3285062 0.2925973 0.2590990
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to have allEffects produce effects for all values of agec?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
probs <-allEffects(m)
```

I needed to add xlevels:

```
probs <-allEffects(m, xlevels=list(agec=1:6))
```

Thanks to @MichaelFriendly for the tip!